# D3 joins with parent and children elements not working as expected

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to use adapt the [D3.js candlestick example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/candlestick-chart).

I am using events to dynamically re-draw the chart as data is being streamed in and the open/close/high/low values are being recalculated.

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work using the current pattern that is used in the example when it comes to drawing lines: New `<line>` elements keep getting appended to each of the `<g>` elements in the DOM each time the function is called. This naturally also breaks transitions (since I'm not updating existing elements in the DOM, but only ever adding new ones).

So I suspect I'm doing the data binding incorrectly somehow? (I'm new to D3, so this is highly probable).

My code looks as follows:

```
// Let's get to drawing
const wrapper2 = d3.select("#wrapper2")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", dimensions.width)
  .attr("height", dimensions.height)

const bounds2 = wrapper2.append("g")
  .style("transform", `translate(${dimensions.margin.left}px, ${dimensions.margin.right}px)`)

// Scales
let xScale2 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, duration])
  .range([0, dimensions.boundedWidth])
  .nice()

let yScale2 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([20, 140])
  .range([0, dimensions.boundedHeight])


const xAxisGenerator2 = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale2).tickFormat(d => d / 1000)
const xAxis2 = bounds2.append("g")
  .call(xAxisGenerator2)
  .style("transform", `translateY(${dimensions.boundedHeight}px)`)

const barsGroup = bounds2.append("g")
function draw2() { // <-- I call this function repeatedly
  // This calculates updated values
  const data = calculateOHLCVForDataSet(ticks, barIndicators);

    const g = barsGroup.selectAll("g")
                       .data(data)
                       .join("g")
                       .style("transform", d => `translateX(${xScale2(d.datetime)}px)`)

  g.append("line")
   .attr("y1", d => yScale2(d.high))
   .attr("y2", d => yScale2(d.low))
   .attr("stroke", "black")

  }
```

On repeated calls of the function, you can see how elements are appended to the DOM instead of transformed.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzQXe.png)

Note that this issue **doesn't** occur when I instead select the lines directly, eg.

```
const g = barsGroup.selectAll("line")
                   .data(data)
                   .join("line")
                   ... // etc.
```

But since I want to use a group (since I want to overlap lines, like in the example), this will not work for my use-case. How do you handle binding data when you do the actual drawing using child elements in D3?

Thanks!